# HTML and PHP syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I again I am lost in syntax. I get caught up in it all and cant see the trees for the forest.

Anyone able to help me with the correct syntax here? I have been trial and erroring for hours. Below is an excerpt from a PHP function. I am tring to have it only display the delete icon if a user is logged in.

```
<td>' .  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { .' <td><a 
href="/inc/delete.php?vid='. $row[0]; .'"><i class='material-icons red-
text'>delete</i></a></td>.' } '. </td>
```

Comment: if you learned how to concatenate things, maybe it would have avoided the question. You should be getting a parse error back for this.

Comment: You removed part of the code, but it seems like you're concatenating an `echo` with an `if`, which you can't.

Comment: and we don't know if you're already in php or not.

Comment: And you seem to be adding a `TD` inside another `TD`.

Comment: yeah, that too ^

Comment: `-- syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: If you want to do a conditional when concatenating strings, use the [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Answer (score 0):

**use following code:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
<td><a href="/inc/delete.php?vid=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><i class='material-icons red-text'>delete</i></a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you are missing the wrapper `<td>` that is in the OP, if you watch closely. plus you can replace `vid=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>` with `vid=<?=$row[0]; ?>` too